# pt-online-schema-change drop_swap doesn't work, so what to do?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, percona-tools

After waiting 24 hours for a `ptosc` this:

```
2023-05-29T11:29:40 Copied rows OK.
2023-05-29T11:29:40 Max rows for the rebuild_constraints method: 2710
Determining the method to update foreign keys...
2023-05-29T11:29:40   `xxx_production`.`click_tracks`: too many rows: 4325947; must use drop_swap                                                                                                  
--alter-foreign-keys-method=drop_swap doesn't work with MySQL 8.0+
See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89441
2023-05-29T11:29:40 Dropping triggers...
2023-05-29T11:29:42 Dropped triggers OK.
Not dropping the new table `xxx_production`.`_orders_new` because --swap-tables failed.  To drop the new table, execute:                                                                           
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `xxx_production`.`_orders_new`;
`xxx_production`.`orders` was not altered.
```

`orders` is a table with 136 million rows. But I think the issue is the `click_tracks` table that has 4.3 million rows. If `drop_swap` must be used, but the next line says `drop_swap` doesn't work on MySQL8....what are we supposed to do exactly?

EDIT:

*Before*

```
mysql> describe orders;
+----------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
...
| item_promotion_id                | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

*After*

```
| item_promotion_id                | varchar(25)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

*Command*

```
pt-online-schema-change --critical-load='Threads_running=600' --alter-foreign-keys-method=auto --execute --alter "MODIFY COLUMN item_promotion_id varchar(25)" D=xxx_production,t=orders
```

Column (item_promotion_id) is NOT in a FK or used in an INDEX.

Could the issue actually be a FK between `orders` and `click_tracks`?

EDIT 2:

Sadly, 'just' running the `ADD COLUMN c VARCHAR, ALGORITHM=INPLACE;` fails on tables so large because we hit `ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry`.
This is described in the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-limitations.html#:%7E:text=The%20following%20limitations%20apply%20to,NULL%20constraints%20on%20the%20table.).

So it seems we are back to `pt-osc` but instead of doing an `ALTER` doing an `ADD`.

EDIT 3:

Trying to do an ADD COLUMN using `pt-osc` results in the same failure!

```
pt-online-schema-change --critical-load='Threads_running=600' --alter-foreign-keys-method=auto --execute --alter "ADD COLUMN item_promotion_ref varchar(25)" D=xxx_production,t=orders
```

```
2023-06-01T06:11:27 Max rows for the rebuild_constraints method: 3090
Determining the method to update foreign keys...
2023-06-01T06:11:27   `xxx_production`.`click_tracks`: too many rows: 4325947; must use drop_swap                                                                         
--alter-foreign-keys-method=drop_swap doesn't work with MySQL 8.0+
See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89441
2023-06-01T06:11:27 Dropping triggers...
2023-06-01T06:11:28 Dropped triggers OK.
Not dropping the new table `xxx_production`.`_orders_new` because --swap-tables failed.  To drop the new table, execute:                                                  
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `xxx_production`.`_orders_new`;
`xxx_production`.`orders` was not altered.
```

I think there is nothing I can do with this table.

Time to hire a DBA.

Comment: What changes were you making with pt-osc?  (Alas, I should blog about why Foreign keys are not worth having.)

Comment: the pt-osc is changing a column type (from id to varchar) on the orders table. Of course, if you know a better way please please let me know! I am stuck with some responsibilities of looking after this huge database.

Comment: And that is the `PRIMARY KEY`?  In which case, it _must_ copy the entire table over, and probably has to jump through hoops to get it done.  Please show me the column definition before and after the change, plus sample values.  I have some thoughts on what to do, but need more details to avoid barking up an unworkable tree.

Comment: And do you have any cases of `ORDER BY id` that would be messed up by changing from int to varchar?  And do you have access to the application code?

Comment: No, it is not a primary key. It is an additional field that is not used in any FK. It MIGHT be used in an index, but I didn't check that. Also ALL the data in that column is the value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think pt-osc is needed for your task.  (In older versions, it was needed for virtually all `ALTERs`.)

Since you are running MySQL 8, you should be able to do

```
ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN item_promo_id VARCHAR ...  ALGORITHM=INPLACE;
```

cf: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl.html

Then change the code to abandon `item_promotion_id` and use `item_promo_id` instead.

`FOREIGN KEYs` are never "required".  They do two things:

- Apply an existence check during `INSERTs`.  This is just "good to have".
- Make sure that it has a suitable `INDEX`.

Note that `ALTER TABLE ... ADD INDEX ... ALGORITHM=INPLACE` is available.  It is not fast, but it is non-invasive.

cf: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html

Comment: Thanks. I was actually thinking to just leave the column and change the code to a new column. Perhaps out of scope, but, in future of course we might need to really use pt-osc on this table. How to do it?

Comment: At least on my test system I get an error of `ERROR 1845 (0A000): ALGORITHM=INSTANT is not supported for this operation. Try ALGORITHM=COPY/INPLACE.` Also on production system of `8.0.23-14 Percona Server `

Comment: Actually 'INSTANT is the default algorithm as of MySQL 8.0.12, and INPLACE before that.' for ADD COLUMN. So I don't need to specify that. I just worry about table locking and taking 24 hours to process the table.